# Video of the Kasparov vs. Kaprov 2009 match in Valencia

Tags: blitz, kasparov, karpov, rapid

Is there a video archive of the (rapid and blitz) match between Kasparov and Karpov that took place in Valencia in 2009? I assume there was a live video coverage with commentary, and I would very much like to watch it. Is there a website where one can (re)watch this match?

Comment: Sadly, the [official website](http://www.matchkarpovkasparov.com/ingles/index.html) does not seem to be very helpful in this (or, indeed, any) regard. I am looking for something like the video archive of the [Kasparov vs. Short match](http://www.uschesschamps.com/battle-legends-kasparov-vs-short/information/battle-legends-kasparov-vs-short) held recently in Saint Louis.

Comment: The live coverage with commentary we have grown so accustomed to, is a development of the last few years. I think I saw the first press conferences on the chessvibes website probably in 2008 and that wasn't yet live. So possibly your assumption is just wrong. But you can go through the comments on http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?tid=69871 , if there is a video archive somewhere it might have been mentioned.

Comment: Ok, looked a bit through the comments myself, apparently there was a video coverage, but the old links are dead. Maybe if you search in spanish ...

Comment: There is a bit on youtube. But looks very incomplete.

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster: Thanks for your comments. [kingscrusher](https://www.youtube.com/user/kingscrusher/) has made an unofficial video annotation of all blitz and rapid games. There are only small parts of the official coverage on YouTube (at least from what I have seen). It's very strange. Apparently, there was an official live video coverage, but the video is nowhere to be found. I mean, we are talking about Kasparov vs. Karpov here... One would assume that the video is available in every corner of the on-line chess world.

Answer (score 1):

I could find replay of live videos, but the commentary wasn't available..! :/
here you can stream those videos

[Kasparov vs Karpov - Valencia, 2009](https://www.youtube.com/user/mecaweb/search?query=kasparov%20vs%20karpov%202009%20valencia)

Comment: I was already aware that there are short videos of the match on Youtube, but I am looking for a replay of the official coverage. The videos you mention contain parts of the official coverage, but there are really not the kind of thing I am looking for.  But thank you for the answer anyway!